# mongoDB : get error "HostNotFound: Could not find address" and "internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968 throw err"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemon

Following message appears on my vscode terminal (code below!)

MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://DB%5Cmongo%5Cnode_modules%5C.bin%5C:27017/test?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-09-15T18:51:58.260+0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server DB\mongo\node_modules.bin:27017, connection attempt failed: HostNotFound: Could not find address for DB\mongo\node_modules.bin:27017: SocketException: No such host is known. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Lim Family\Desktop\node\lecture\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

While running npm start which runs "nodemon app.js" as defined in package.json.
I've set IP address whitelist to all IP addresses. Additionally user and connection string simply copied paste from mongodb atlas.

Can someone explain where the error is, and also for the second error, cannot find module...., ive created a fresh project and installed all the dependencies but that one wont go away. Might be just me but i think nodemon is not running properly as well, doesnt have the [nodemon] prefix

[edit] now getting a different error:

MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
exception: Database name cannot have reserved characters for mongodb:// URL: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DB%5CNew
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
throw err;
^

```js
const mongoConnect = (callback) => {
  MongoClient.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://wesleynodejs:(passwordICopiedFromMongoDb)@learning.2fvkd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
  )
    .then((client) => {
      console.log("CONNECTED TO MONGODB");
      _db = client.db();
      callback();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Ensure your password is properly URI escaped.

Answer (score 0):

[solved] Saw a post regarding my second error “internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968 throw err” explaining that it is caused having some .js files with same names in different directories, which were in the same main directory.

Changing my file location WORKED for me, although i dont see how this magically solves my connection error!

hope this helps others as I was mildly confused to find next to nothing on “HostNotFound: Could not find address” for mongoDB